# I cant make for loop work in function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function which puts a text in `abc div` and with the for loop i want to show 10 random text in that div. I cant make my function work in for loop, it works for once then stops. How can i make it for more?

```
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        $("#abc").text(rand);
    }, 1000);
}
$('#start').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myFunction();
    };
})
```

Comment: I suspect it does run more than once, but since you're always setting the text of the same element you can only see the final result.

Comment: Javascript is very fast - add a `setTimeout` with a variable length of time if you want to see the intermediate values

Comment: There should not be a semicolon after the for loop but instead after your click event listener, that's a start but not your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this?** — http://jsfiddle.net/PQmj2/

What you need to do is add a delay between each setTimeout call.

```
function myFunction(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        $("#abc").text(rand);
    }, 1000 * i);
}
$('#start').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myFunction(i);
    };
})
```

What I'm doing here is passing in the value of `i` to `myFunction`. That way, there is a delay of 1 second between each call i.e. `1000 * 1` = 1 second, `1000 * 2` = 2 seconds, `1000 * 3` = 3 seconds, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop schedules 10 calls to `myFunction`, all of which will happen one right after another one second later. If you want to schedule 10 calls to run (say) one per second over the course of 10 seconds, you have to use a different interval for the second, third, fourth, etc.

```
function myFunction(count) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        $("#abc").text(rand);
    }, 1000 * count);
}
$('#start').click(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        myFunction(i);
    };
})
```

There I'm passing `i` into `myFunction` (as `count`). Note that I changed the loop to be from `1` to `10` (inclusive) instead of `0` to `9` so that `count * 1000` in `myFunction` would be `1000` for the first loop iteration (since you seemed to want the first one to happen after one second, rather than immediately).

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that your setTimeout is not working, it's that it's setting 10 1-second timeouts at the same time, so they are all firing at the same time 1 second later.  What you want to do is stagger your timeouts based on the index of your loop:

```
function myFunction() {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $("#abc").text(rand);
}
$('#start').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, i * 1000);
    };
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` is calling something delayed. Use `setInterval` when you want it to repeat.